# Aggregate Date Range filtered values in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, range-query

I need to filter a group of values based on date (added field here) and then group it by `device_id`.  So I am using the following thing :

```
{
  "aggs":{
    "dates_between":{
      "filter": {
        "range" : {
          "added" : {
            "gte": "2014-07-01 00:00:00",
            "lte" :"2014-08-01 00:00:00"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_device_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "device_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving me an error `"Failed to parse source"` when executing the query. This is the right way of doing it ?

If I execute the date aggregation only it is showing values which are not in the specified date range

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the other way around `dates_between` is a nested aggregation of `group_by_device_id`

```
"aggs": {
    "group_by_device_id": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "device_id"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "dates_between": {
                "filter": {
                    "range": {
                        "added": {
                            "gte": "2014-07-01 00:00:00",
                            "lte": "2014-08-01 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also move the filter into the the query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "added": {
                        "gte": "2014-07-01 00:00:00",
                        "lte": "2014-08-01 00:00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_device_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "device_id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```